# Is a custom AutoMapper ValueResolver an (in)appropriate place for fetching data?

Tags: asp.net, automapper

Let's say that in my ASP.NET MVC project, I have a ViewModel that is used on a form for editing a product. Among many other fields, I have a list of product types I want the user to be able to select from, in a dropdown.

When I map my domain object to my ViewModel, I'm calling a service to fetch the domain object, then using AutoMapper to map it to the ViewModel. To fill a dropdown for that list of product types, I call another service, which fetches that data from the database and uses it to populate another property on my ViewModel.

What I'm wrestling with is whether it's better to call that secondary service explicitly in the controller, versus potentially putting that call into a custom ValueResolver class and configuring my mapping to use it.

I like the prospect of removing the dependency on the product type service from my controller (because there are a lot of these, and the controller ends up with a lot of dependencies), but I'm worried that putting this sort of logic (which can hit the database) into a ValueResolver is an inappropriate use of a ValueResolver and might violate what I'd call the principle of least surprise. (I.e., I probably wouldn't expect mapping code to be causing database requests.)

Is this a common thing to use a ValueResolver for?

Answer (score 1):

Answered by [Jimmy Bogard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58508/jimmy-bogard) on the [AutoMapper Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/automapper-users/LXCJA7IMVFw/discussion):

> Yeah, it's definitely not uncommon. Drop-down list data sources....man, they're the toughest thing to figure out in our ViewModel world.
>
> Keep in mind that you'll need to worry about the POST scenarios, refilling-in the information for validation failures, etc.

Comment: I see what you're saying and i've seen it done like this in several places but to me it still feels wrong.  Doesn't it violate the single responsibility principle?  Not only are the mappers responsible for mapping but they are also now responsible for fetching data from some service/database.  From a consumers point of view (calling Map(<>,<>)), isn't it a side effect if the routine is performing more than just the mapping?